# Convert [h]:mm:ss to mm:ss in Excel

Tags: excel, datetime, time, excel-formula

I have a data-set collected from GPS tracker. The total time in the data should be  mm:ss. But Excel is interpreting it as hours and minutes.

How can I use a formula to convert it to Minutes and seconds? In the example below, 32 is supposed to be 32 minutes and 15 is supposed to be 15 seconds.

[image: attached the screenshot of the dataset]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: It seems that the real issue is that the number before the colon is supposed to be minutes, but it has been stored as hours. So this is not just a display issue. You need to divide by 60 to turn hours to minutes and minutes to seconds.

The text function allows you to display numbers in a different format. You can also apply this format: [mm]:ss in the cell itself using cell formatting without using a formula.

If you want the total minutes:

```
=TEXT(A1/60,"[mm]:ss")
```

If you only want the minutes excluding hte hours:

```
=TEXT(A1/60,"mm:ss")
```

Comment: Thanks @Greg. 

I think I am not clear with my question.
I need the data to be in mm:ss(32:15) and that is how it is displayed. But, it is actually in the [h]:mm:ss format(1/1/1900  8:15:00 AM).

Comment: I think I know what you mean now. I edited my answer.

Comment: Perfect!! Got the answer. Thanks a lot, @GregViers.

Answer (score 0):

An hour has 60 minutes. Thus, if you multiply the hour times 60, you would get the number of the minutes. Then you should add the seconds:

```
=HOUR(A2)*60 & ":" & SECOND(A2)
```

---

From the comment:
*The table displays the data correctly already. For record A2, the minutes in 32 and the seconds is 15.*

If you think that your data is correct, then I have some bad news for you.
Long story short - On C1, D1 and E1 write the following:

```
=Hour(A2)
=Minute(A2)
=Second(A2)
```

Then it will show:

```
8
15
0
```

Comment: The table displays the data correctly already. For record A2, the minutes in 32 and the seconds is 15.

I just wanted to remove that 1/1/1900  8:15:00 AM format from the record and save the data in mm:ss format only.

Comment: @vishnuprashanth - there is no formula in `A2` or am I mistaken?

Comment: Apologies, it not the formula, but the format.

I want my data to be in mm:ss (32:15) format.
But in the formula tab, the value is shown as 1/1/1900  8:15:00 AM.

Comment: @vishnuprashanth - have you tried the formula? It removes the `1/1/1900` and it converts the hours to minutes?

Comment: yes, I have tried. There is no hours in the data. it is 32 minutes and 15 seconds and 00 milliseconds. I don't need to convert hours to minutes.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear based on @vishnuprashanth comments.